# Selenium chromedriver hangs if I specify user-data-dir in Chrome options

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

If I specify chrome_options, then it hangs:

```
params = {'executable_path': path_to_driver}
if self._chrome_options is not None:
    params['chrome_options'] = self._chrome_options
print "# before construct"
self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(**params)
print "# after construct"
```

So, the message `after_construct` is not shown. In `chrome_options` I passed the string:

```
user-data-dir=/home/sergzach/.config/google-chrome
```

So, the Chrome is starting and entering into my normal profile. But the `Python` script hangs on construction the `self._driver` and I can't continue to work with the Python script.

If I do not pass `self._chrome_options` (`None`) then all is OK: Chrome is starting and execution is going farther (both `before_construct` and `after_construct` are printing).

If I pass empty `chrome_options`:

```
webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

then it doesn't hang.

> Installed Chrome version: **55.0.2883.75 (64-bit)**
>
> webdriver version: **2.25.426924**
>
> OS: **Ubuntu.**

**Update**

There is a traceback (it raises in about 20 seconds after script hangs):

`File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    w.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/walker/walker.py", line 164, in start
    self._driver = webdriver.Chrome(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64`

**Update**

It causes because Chrome can't connect to remote debugger. I output the log:

`...
params.update(service_args=['--verbose'])
params.update(service_log_path='/tmp/selenium.log')
...
self._chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
...`

And I see the [reason](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=878). But I do not realise how to switch off the option `--remote-debugging-port=xxxx` which is passing to chrome driver. OK, let's analyze the sources further.

Comment: What is the value of `self._chrome_options`?

Comment: @alecxe It works normal with a value `webdriver.ChromeOptions()`, but if I do `self._chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/sergzach/.config/google-chrome")` then it hangs.

Comment: @alecxe Yes, I tried also `chown -R sergzach:sergzach` the directory. The result is same.

Comment: @alecxe The Python script hangs, not the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only one client could be connected to a debugger in one time. So, to fix the issue, when we want to enter to a user profile using a debugger - to avoid chromedriver hangs trying to connect to the debugger, we must close an existing Chrome session (I share [this conversation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=878) one more time).

Comment: Ah, always encounter this issue, was not able to recognize it by these symptoms. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I get round this by killing all the chrome processes first:

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print(proc)
    # Check whether the process name matches or not
    if proc.name() == 'chrome' or proc.name() == 'chromedriver':
        proc.kill()
```